# Possible to make QDialog shake in OSx

Tags: c++, macos, qt

Since Qt is using Cocoa under OSX, is it possible to make a modal QDialog to shake if the user enters the wrong password for example? Im not able to find anything about it but it would be really nice to implement on mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a built-in way to do it, but you could implement the shaking yourself, like this:

header.h

```
#include <QtGui>

class ShakyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void shake()
    {
        static int numTimesCalled = 0;
        numTimesCalled++;

        if (numTimesCalled == 9) {
            numTimesCalled = 0;
            return;
        }

        vacillate();
        QTimer::singleShot(40, this, SLOT(shake()));
    }

private:
    void vacillate()
    {
        QPoint offset(10, 0);

        move(((shakeSwitch) ? pos() + offset : pos() - offset));
        shakeSwitch = !shakeSwitch;
    }

    bool shakeSwitch;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    ShakyDialog dialog;
    QHBoxLayout layout(&dialog);
    QPushButton button("Push me.");
    layout.addWidget(&button);

    QObject::connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &dialog, SLOT(shake()));

    dialog.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I don't know (and I think there's no) a built in solution in Qt. But as Anthony suggested you can implement it pretty easily. As a note: maybe it's even easier to implement it with QTimeLine ( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimeline.html ) - this way you only have to create the time-line and set it's parameters and connect it to the position-x coordinate.